# Sorting arrays with MobX

Tags: javascript, mobx, mobx-react

We have an MobX store containing an "User" object, which have "Comments" (array) on it.

```
{
   user: {
       name: "",
       comments: []
   }     
}
```

In our view, we want to display the comments sorted by created date

in the view the bound value is `this.props.store.user.comments.sort(...)`
This looks like it works initially, but adding entries to the comments breaks the sorting.

```
addComment = text => this.user.comments.push(....);
```

When reading https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/issues/166

I'm starting to think I need to expose the comments array some other way to the view, should my store expose the sorted array separately somehow?

Magic is nice, until it stops working, and here I am :-)

after @Tholle's reply, I've tried various options with no luck.
I'm getting `this.props.store.sortedEventLog.map is not a function``

Am I doing something strange here?

```
class ContactStore {
 constructor() {
  extendObservable(this, {
    loading: false,
    contact: {
      Name: "",
      Email: "",
      CellPhone: "",
      Phone: "",
      AllAreaOfExpertises: [],
      EventLog: [],
      qualityItems: [],
      Tags: []
    },
    AvailableTags: []
  });

  // this doesnt work
  // this.sortedEventLog = computed(() =>
  //   this.contact.EventLog.sort(
  //     (a, b) => b.Audit.Created.Date - a.Audit.Created.Date
  //   )
  // );
}

// this doesn't work either
// sortedEventLog = computed(() =>
//   this.contact.EventLog.sort(
//     (a, b) => b.Audit.Created.Date - a.Audit.Created.Date
//   )
// );

// this doesn't work either
// get sortedEventLog() {
//   return computed(() =>
//     this.contact.EventLog.sort(
//       (a, b) => b.Audit.Created.Date - a.Audit.Created.Date
//     )
//   );
// }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [**computed**](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/computed-decorator.html) and return a sorted array:

**Example ([JSBin](http://jsbin.com/dabobonara/edit?js,output))**

```
class Store {
  @observable user = {
    name: "Eric",
    comments: [{
      text: 'First comment',
      date: Date.now()
    }]
  }

  @computed get sortedComments() {
    return this.user.comments.sort((a, b) => b.date - a.date);
  }

  addComment = text => this.user.comments.push({
    text: Math.random().toString(36).substring(7),
    date: Date.now()
  });
}
```

Alternatively, you could use [**replace**](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/array.html) in your `addComment` function to sort them when you add a new one:

**Example ([JSBin](http://jsbin.com/doyogimizu/1/edit?js,output))**

```
class Store {
  @observable user = {
    name: "Eric",
    comments: [{
      text: 'First comment',
      date: Date.now()
    }]
  }

  @action addComment(text) {
    this.user.comments.push({
      text: Math.random().toString(36).substring(7),
      date: Date.now()
    });
    const sortedArray = this.user.comments.sort((a, b) => b.date - a.date);
    this.user.comments.replace(sortedArray);
  }
}
```

Comment: I've tried all sorts of options now with no luck, please see above edit. any ideas? (I don't have decorator support)

Comment: @RogerJohansson Have you stumbled upon [**this part of the documentation**](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/computed-decorator.html#-computed-modifier)? `@computed get propertyName() { } is basically sugar for extendObservable(this, { propertyName: get func() { } }) in the constructor call.` So you could try `extendObservable(this, { ... , sortedEventLog: computed(function() { return this.contact.EventLog.sort((a, b) => b.Audit.Created.Date - a.Audit.Created.Date); }) })`

Comment: I honestly feel so stupid right now. holy shit.. you see b.date - a.date.... the dates are in ISO String format... string - string = NaN...